# Not been able to check radio button in knockout using type script

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, typescript

That's how my radio button is bound,

```
<input type="radio" name="none" value="-1" data-bind="enable: isEnabled, checked: isNoneChecked" />None
```

It's a Typescript code and isNoneChecked is defined like this,

```
isNoneChecked: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
```

In constructor I am simply setting it up 'true',

```
this.isNoneChecked(true);
```

I expect on page load this radio button to be checked.

Its seems not working.

Comment: radio button `value` & `checked` binded values should be same in your case make `value="true"` and check & also you need to make `this.isNonChecked("true")` . cheers

Comment: sample here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25273/ . anything let us know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

super cool is right,

Here is the TypeScript,

```
class ViewModel {
    constructor() {
        this.isNoneChecked('true');
    }
    isNoneChecked: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable('false');
}
```

Thanks